# Check if Javascript is enabled server side ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Is it possible to check if the client browser has javascript enabled from ASP.NET code?

I was hoping to ideally do this on PreRender of controls, or PageLoad, so that I can change how they look.

Any suggestions, work arounds etc would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do it, without making a subsequent request I'm afraid.

There are explanations that can be found by doing a search on Google most use an AJAX call or a hidden field that gets popluated via some javascript, that won't get run if Javascript is disabled.

If you have to do it then I'd try doing it on the very first request from the client, and save a cookie (or somethign similar), then check the value of the cookie on subsequent requests. This assumes that the user doesn't enable / disable Javascript often. You could also store a value in the session.

I hope that helps

Comment: I was hoping for something cleaner but if that's the only way that can be done... I'll store it in a session var and have an accessor method to make it cleaner.

Answer (score 7):

Page.Request.Browser.EcmaScriptVersion will indicate what *ASP.NET* thinks is true.  This assumes that the BrowserCaps are correct. It does give you a first pass indication which is probably pretty close.

**EDIT:** I initially misunderstood the question (enabled vs. supported).  You could use the BrowserCaps server side to weed out those UserAgents that *don't* support JavaScript. Then use one line of script on each request to determine if it is enabled via cookie:

```
// let the server know JavaScript is enabled via session cookie
document.cookie = "js=1; path=/";
```

Then detect existence server-side:

```
HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("js");
bool js = (cookie != null) && (cookie.Value == "1");
```

Once they close the browser this cookie will go away.

Answer (score 0):

i think this artical will usefull to check the javascript enable or not from server side
[check if javascript is enabled from server side](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26418/Check-if-JavaScript-is-Enabled-from-Server-Side-Us)